# .htaccess Rule needed for inner pages

Tags: .htaccess

I have URLs like

```
www.domain-name.com/in/landline-phones.html
www.domain-name.com/in/computer-storage.html
www.domain-name.com/in/furniture.html

and so on, more than 200 URLs
```

"/in/" in URL is not static, this may be usa, uk any country code.

In .htacess, I need rules to call below URL format. "source=seo_url" is static

```
www.domain-name.com/search?country=in&source=seo_url&keyword=landline-phones.html
www.domain-name.com/search?country=in&source=seo_url&keyword=computer-storage.html
www.domain-name.com/search?country=in&source=seo_url&keyword=furniture.html

and so on for all URLs
```

What I have done already:

```
www.domain-name.com/furniture.html
```

Below is the rule I have used

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ search.php?keyword=$1
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two matching groups for your url try below rule

**Edit**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([\w]+)/([\w-]+).html$ test2.php?country=$1&source=seo_url&keyword=$2.html [L]
```

Comment: will this also consider same format if I use domain-name.com/in/terms.html?

Comment: yes it is based for `domain-name.com/in/terms.html` you please try then tell me if it works for you.

Comment: No, it passed rules and shows page not found. Shows URL www.domain-name.com/in/landline-phones.html